# Where can I find proper Android Source Code for preview version N?

Tags: android, android-source

Android N preview 4 installed on my Nexus 5x phone. Build number NPD56N. I want to understand some of bugs. For that I need debugging on android source code. I found that all accessible source code of View class is out of date.

1. I was trying use android-MNC source code from android SDK folder.
2. I was trying to find proper code on the Github. But the oldest version of needed class dated by 2016-03-29. https://api.github.com/repos/android/platform_frameworks_base/commits?path=core/java/android/view/View.java

Is there any solution to find the latest source code or Google hide the latest source code before release?

Answer (score 1):

Probably here you have the latest version:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master

And [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-n-preview-4) is the N Preview 4 code (latest update 9.06.2016)

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-n-preview-4 would be better, insofar as that should line up with N Developer Preview 4.

Comment: By the links I found same old code for the View class.